Is it possible to integrate with HID barcode scanners using tauri 2.0?
I know Tauri has a plugin to scan barcodes with device cameras, but I would like to scan using Android Scanners equipped with a laser scanner.
I have come across this doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebHID_API on the WebHID_API but from the looks of it this feature is still experimental and so not available on most browsers/engines.
It is however said to be available/usable in chrome,edge>=89 and opera>=75.
My question is, can Tauri's webview run this API?
